# No Gnome Version Available?

Tags: gnome, 23.10, ubuntu-budgie

I have a Ubuntu Budgie 23.10. I go into `Settings > About > System Details` and this is what I see:

[image]

Why is `gnome` not available? Is it because I am on Budgie?

Answer (score 4):

`GNOME Version: Not available` simply means that the system cannot locate a Gnome Desktop stack to query the version.

This is expected behavior for a stock install of Ubuntu Budgie.

Many components of Budgie are originally based upon (or forked from) GNOME, but Budgie is not GNOME. Installing Ubuntu Budgie does **not** also install GNOME.